# Equidistant points on a circle

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

I would like to obtain/generate points on a circle in Cartesian coordinates such that the distance between two consecutive points will be always equal. For example, plotting a circle with radius 100 with each point 1 unit away from the previous and the next point.

I have tried to use polar coordinates as well as the R=x^2+y^2, but could not achieve what I wanted. What would be a reasonable approach for determining those points on a circle?

Comment: I couldn't figure out the formula but people have written code for it at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44415/choosing-n-equidistant-points-on-a-circle-with-given-radius-and-center

Comment: It may not be possible given specific pairs $R,d$ to make $n$ points around the circle, each at distance $d$ from the previous one. That is, after nearly once around, it may happen that the "next" point placed would not wind up exactly where the first one was, and would thus end up between the first two generated points. This goes whether the distance is found along the arc or found as the straight line distance.

Comment: Thank you for the link and information @user45195, I think this is the answer to my new evolved question

Comment: Thank you @coffeemath , combined with the link above this will definitely help me. After realizing that it might be impossible to fit those points with fixed spacing as I wanted, I need to change my way of thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your example of $R=100$ and $d=1$, you get a central angle of

$$\alpha=2\arcsin\frac{d}{2R}\approx0.573°\approx\frac{2\pi}{628}$$

So your points wouls most closely resemble a regular $628$-gon. But not exactly: the $628$-gon has $d\approx1.0005$ while the $629$-gon has $d\approx0.9989$. Therefore you can't place points at unit distance from one another along a circle of radius $100$ all the way around. Not exactly.

But perhaps you only want points on a part of the circle, so they don't have to get back exactly to their starting point. Or perhaps a slight deviation in radius or distance is acceptable. Then you can get coordinates for your points using

$$ x_k = R\cos(k\alpha) \qquad y_k = R\sin(k\alpha) $$

for $k\in\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$. If you aim for an exact $n$-gon, you'd use $\alpha=\frac{2\pi}n$ while for exact lengths $R$ and $d$ but a non-closing sequence you'd use the angle as computed above.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very clear answer to realize the concept and I am marking your answer as accepted one. It is good for me to realize that it may not be good to use equidistant spacing. Although the approximation might be okay for some cases, it is 5mm difference for each point and the error accumulate as I go through the points. 

By the way, if it is not required to be equidistant by 1 meter, but `x` meter away from each other depending on the circle and having certain number of points (i.e. 1000) on it, how would be the approach then?

Comment: @birincilikteli: I'm not sure about this “error accumulates”, since the distance between two non-adjacent points will not be the sum of the distances to some intermediate point. Also note that I was using direct distance along a line, not the length of the circle arc between the points. If you have $d$ and $n$, then you can compute the minimal $R$ from that by turning my fodmulas above around. Start with $R=1$, compute $d$ from that using the given $n$, then the $R$ you want is the inverse of the $d$ you just computed.

Comment: I meant "error accumulates", because my piece of code was assuming a fixed distance as 1 and making calculations on that even though it is not exactly one, thus I would rather improve it to take the actual distance into account so that the error will not accumulate. Furthermore your calculation is just as I wanted, because I need to use linear interpolation between points which is exactly same as you did to find the distance in between, which is actually an n-gon that n is large so that it is smooth (or a discretized circle by definition)